# Converting a byte array to .wav file in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, wav

Working on trying to translate a byte array into a new .wav file in Android Studio.

I originally take a .wav file and transform it into a byte array to do some signal processing on the wav (filtering). Then I intend on transforming it back into a .wav file for audio outputting.

Since I am working in Android Studio I cannot easily use the AudioInputStream or .write classes/methods in Java.

So my main question is HOW do you go from a byte array to a .wav file.

Here is what I have so far:
Code to transform the .wav file into a byte array:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out;
out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
InputStream in = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.car); //references the wav file to in
int read;
byte[] buff = new byte[2000000];

    try {
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0)
        {
            out.write(buff, 0, read);//reads the wav file and places it inside in
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    //creates a byte Array and stores it into audioBytes
    byte[] audioBytes = out.toByteArray();

/*
code to do signal processing on byte array
*/
/*
code to transform the byte array BACK into a .wav file
*/
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what the question is.

Comment: I have a byte array, and I want to transform that byte array into a .wav file for audio playback. But I cannot use classes like AudioInputStream. Are there other methods in doing so?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html

Comment: What you want has nothing to do with a wav file. You want to put a file in a byte array and after that save the byte array to file again. I bet if you google for save byte array to file you will find suitable code.